# Help me write this query in SQL

Tags: sql-server, query

I'm trying to get help writing a query from scratch SQL.

Thanks

Here is Question:

*Find email addresses dbo.[EmailAdresses] that are not associated with any person dbo.[Person]. Return [EmailAddress] and [EmailAddressID] from the table dbo.[EmailAdresses].
Provide different requests using LEFT, RIGHT JOINs and without joining tables*

Its all for study? i want to become professional worker with databases, but sometimes i cant find answers on my questions=(

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT EmailAddress FROM dbo.[EmailAdresses] NOT LIKE *not idea*

SELECT EmailAddress, EmailAddressID FROM dbo.[EmailAdresses]